# Is there a command to explicit the Ubuntu flavour?

Tags: command-line

I know that the `lsb_release` command `echo`es the Ubuntu version I'm currently using. But is there a command that prompts the system flavor (`Ubuntu`, `Lubuntu`, `Kubuntu`, `Edubuntu`, etc.) I'm in?
Like:

```
$ the_command
Ubuntu
```

If I'm using Ubuntu or

```
$ the_command
Lubuntu
```

If I'm using Lubuntu?

Comment: Try `cat /etc/os-release`

Comment: Does `lsb_release -i | cut -f2` suffice?

Answer (score 1):

Try `lsb_release -a`

```
$lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.4 (jessie)
Release:    8.4
Codename:   jessie
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ lsb_release -si
Ubuntu
```

should cut it.